# Package not compiling after update

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosmake, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

I just updated the ros-fuerte- realted things from ubuntu software center and the packages which were working and compiling before are showing this error.

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
[rosbuild] Building package depth_odometry
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only depth_odometry
CMake Error at /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:16 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  Command add_executable() is not scriptable
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:231 (INCLUDE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/vtk_include.cmake:1 (find_package)




CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  

  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'depth_odometry'.
  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64480/package-not-compiling-after-update/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That was caused by [this bug](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/18) in PCL. The next update should solve this issue; in the meanwhile, just do this:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1